# Authorize requests to ASP.NET Core 2.1 application using ADFS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, adfs

I have an ADFS server.

I added a Relying Party Trust based on this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Now I want to build an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application that will be published as a self contained Linux-x64 application.

The application is intended to be a single page JS and React application which will be viewed by users connected to the domain configured on the ADFS server mentioned above.

I want that users connected to that domain to be automatically authorized to display the main page and all users from outside the domain to have to authenticate themselves before they can access the page.

How do I configure the ASP.NET Core application in order to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 0):

[Integrated windows auth](https://docs.centrify.com/Content/CoreServices/Authenticate/SilentAuthBrowsers.htm) (IWA / WIA) achieves this.

This is browser functionality.

This only works for domain joined PC.